# is there any recommended way to scan nexus repository to retrieve the jar?

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I am developing a java REST API to retrieve the jar based on GAV coordinates from nexus repository. I saw NexusIndexer (https://maven.apache.org/maven-indexer/apidocs/org/apache/maven/index/NexusIndexer.html ) documentation to scan the jars from remote repository. It seems to confusing to me, I am wondering if anyone can have simple solution for that.

Any leads would be helpful here.

Comment: What do you want to retrieve, based on which criteria? Without this, your question is totally unclear.

Comment: I want to retrieve jar based on GAV co-ordinates. I have updated my question.

Comment: You could make use of the original libraries from org.eclipse.aether that are also used by Maven to work with artifacts.

Comment: Why not using Maven itself???

Comment: @Robert  Could you please provide example code?

Comment: @khmarbaise Could you please provide example code?

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_setup_Maven

Comment: Your question is too broad to provide sample code. But we are talking about an open source library that is documented and used in various other open source projects, so just search for it you will find a code where org.eclipse.aether is used.